# PHP: Function that accepts a birthday date as a parameter and returns the day of the week from this year

Tags: php

Submit a date (example: 1982-05-20) from a form and returns the day of the week from this year.

1) form to submit date:

```
<form action="Date2.php" method="post" align="center">
    <input name="date" size="20" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" type="text" required="">
    <input name="submit" value="Submit" type="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

2) PHP part: create a function that accepts a date as a parameter (from the form) and returns the day of the week (Monday, or Tuesday, etc.) Function will be used in the following code:

```
<?
//How many dates do you need to put in the array????
$datearray = array("1/1/2016", "date", "date",......);
foreach ($datearray as $key => $date) {
    echo(myDateFunction($date));
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function to fetch name of the day. Note it will throw an exception in case of error.

```
function fetchDay($date)
{
    return (new DateTime($date))->format('l');
}
```

For instance `fetchDay('2016-04-02')` will return `"Saturday"`

An the function to fetch a day of the current year

```
function fetchDay($date)
{
    $dateTime = new DateTime($date);
    $currentYear = date('Y');
    $month = $dateTime->format('m');
    $day = $dateTime->format('d');

    if(!checkdate($month, $day, $currentYear))
    {
        throw new Exception('Invalid Gregorian date');
    }

    $dateTime->setDate($currentYear, $month, $day);

    return $dateTime->format('l');
}
```

Comment: That makes sense.....I'll try that out. For : $datearray = array("1/1/2016", "date", "date",......); How many dates need to be typed out? Thank you for helping. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @HLD What do you mean?

Comment: In my book it is saying that if you add more dates to the array, the function should work. Do I need to list every date of a year or just some. That is what has me confused.

Comment: The function will work regardless of number of dates in the array.

Comment: Ok we are getting closer! When I type in 1982-05-20 (year-month-day) it gives me Saturday when it needs to be Friday of this year. But I am getting closer!

Comment: 1982-05-20 was Thursday

Comment: Taking a birthday from past and getting the day that it lands on of this year. Like 1982-05-20 would be Friday of this year.

Comment: Or you mean to display a day in 2016? If so you need to change year of the date like this ```$dateTime->setDate(date('Y'), $dateTime->format('m'), $dateTime->format('d'));```

Comment: Updated my answer. The second function will check if date is valid for the current year and return name of the day in the current year.

Comment: I just noticed your edit above...gonna look at that now. Thank you